# Posterior Predictive Check (PPC) for a Bayesian linear regression model: Edward's result is pretty different from PyMC3's?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, pymc

I'm trying to build a simple Bayesian regression model to test Edward. However, I notice significant different between Edward's PPC results and PyMC3's.

#### Common code to generate a data set.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def generateData(intercept=1, slope=3, noise=1, n_points=20):
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.random.uniform(-3, 3, size=n_points)})
    df['y'] = intercept + slope * df['x'] + np.random.np.random.normal(0, scale=noise, size=n_points)
    df = df.sort_values(['x'], ascending=True).reset_index(drop=True)
    return df

intercept = 1
slope = 3
noise = 1
np.random.seed(99)
data = generateData(intercept=intercept, slope=slope, noise=noise)
```

The training data looks like the following:

[image]

After a Bayesian regression model is built via PyMC3 and Edward, respectively, I plot the PPC distributions, as shown below:

[image]

It seems a bit odd to me that Edward's PPC distribution is so skewed and much wider than PyMC3's result?

## Appendix

#### PyMC3 code for a Bayesian linear regression

```
import pymc3 as pm

xvals = data['x'].values
yvals = data['y'].values
with pm.Model() as model:

    BURN_IN_STEPS = 2000
    MCMC_STEPS = 4000

    # Specify priors
    sigma = pm.HalfCauchy('sigma', beta=10, testval=1.0)    
    beta0 = pm.Normal('beta0', 0.0, sd=10.0)
    beta1 = pm.Normal('beta1', 0.0, sd=10.0)

    # Specify likelihood
    likelihood = pm.Normal('y', mu=beta0 + beta1 * xvals, sd=sigma,
                           observed=yvals)

    # MCMC 
    start = pm.find_MAP()
    trace = pm.sample(BURN_IN_STEPS+MCMC_STEPS, start=start, step=pm.NUTS())
    trace = trace[BURN_IN_STEPS:]

# Get PPC
posterior_predictive_checks = pm.sample_ppc(trace, model=model, samples=1000, progressbar=False)
y_replicas = [y_rep.mean() for y_rep in posterior_predictive_checks['y']]
```

#### Plot PyMC3 PPC

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(11, 6.5))
ax.hist(y_replicas, bins=20, alpha=0.5, color="#348ABD", histtype="stepfilled", label="replica")
ax.axvline(yvals.mean(), color="#A60628", label="data")
ax.legend(loc=2, fontsize=FONTSIZE)
ax.set_xlabel("mean(y)", fontsize=20, labelpad=15)
_ = ax.set_title("PPC in PyMC3", fontsize=FONTSIZE)
```

#### Edward code for a linear regression

```
import edward as ed
import tensorflow as tf

N = 20
D = 1
X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [N, D])
sigma = ed.models.Chi2(df=3.0)
w = ed.models.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(D), scale=tf.ones(D)*10.0)
b = ed.models.Normal(loc=tf.zeros(1), scale=tf.ones(1)*10.0)
y = ed.models.Normal(loc=ed.dot(X, w)+b, scale=tf.ones(N)*sigma)

T = 10000

qs = ed.models.Empirical(params=tf.Variable(tf.ones(T)))
qw = ed.models.Empirical(params=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((T, D) )))
qb = ed.models.Empirical(params=tf.Variable(tf.random_normal((T, 1) )))

inference = ed.HMC({sigma: qs, w: qw, b: qb}, 
                   data={X: data[['x']].values, y: data['y'].values})
inference.run(step_size=3e-3)

# Get PPC
y_post = ed.copy(y, {w: qw, b: qb, sigma: qs})
T = lambda ys, _: tf.reduce_mean(y_post)
ppc_stats = ed.ppc(T, 
                   data={X: data[['x']].values, y: data['y'].values},
                   latent_vars={w: qw, b: qb, sigma: qs},
                   n_samples=1000)
```

#### Plot Edward PPC:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(11, 6.5))
ax.hist(ppc_stats[0], bins=20, alpha=0.5, color="#348ABD", histtype="stepfilled", label="replica")
ax.axvline(data['y'].values.mean(), color="#A60628", label="data")
ax.legend(loc=2, fontsize=FONTSIZE)
ax.set_xlabel("mean(y)", fontsize=FONTSIZE, labelpad=15)
_ = ax.set_title("PPC in Edward", fontsize=FONTSIZE)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the primary issue with the Edward code is that the `step_size` in your inference step is too small. When the step size is too small, it prevents the MCMC sampler from adequately exploring the sample space, which you can tell was happening because the acceptance rate was 1.0. Even though HMC is more efficient than vanilla MCMC you should still expect to reject some samples. When I changed the stepsize to 1.5e-1 I started getting sensible results, as you can see here:

[image]

Also, not sure if this makes a difference (I just started learning Edward today) but it seems like in general, when examining posterior output, most of the examples I've seen use `y_post` rather than `y`, 
i.e.

```
ppc_stats = ed.ppc(T, 
                   data={X: data[['x']].values, y_post: data['y'].values},
                   latent_vars={w: qw, b: qb, sigma: qs},
                   n_samples=1000)
```

instead of

```
ppc_stats = ed.ppc(T, 
                   data={X: data[['x']].values, y: data['y'].values},
                   latent_vars={w: qw, b: qb, sigma: qs},
                   n_samples=1000)
```